# Twisted load balancer with different types of proxies

Tags: python, proxy, twisted, load-balancing

I'm trying to make simple load balancer that supports different types of proxies.

```py
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.portforward import ProxyFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from enum import Enum
import random

class BalancerType(Enum):
    SOCKS5 = 'SOCKS5'
    HTTP = 'HTTP'

class BalancerFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
        self.proxy_factories = [ProxyFactory('127.0.0.1', 20000), ProxyFactory('127.0.0.1', 30000)]

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        proxy_factory = random.choice(self.proxy_factories)
        print 'using proxy %s:%s' % (proxy_factory.host, proxy_factory.port)
        return proxy_factory.buildProtocol(addr)

reactor.listenTCP(interface = '127.0.0.1', port = 10000, factory = BalancerFactory(BalancerType.SOCKS5))
reactor.run()
```

The balancer listens on 127.0.0.1:10000 and randomly distributes http requests to proxy servers at 127.0.0.1:20000, 127.0.0.1:30000.
All is working just fine when I configure a web browser to use socks proxy and all my proxies in balancer are socks proxies.

But I need to support different type of proxies, for example socks5 proxy at 127.0.0.1:20000 and http proxy at 127.0.0.1:30000.

I think I need some extra factory to wrap connection if balancer type and proxy type are different.

I tried to find some socks 5 library that supports twisted. **txsocksx** looks great, but all examples are using endpoints and I don't know how to use it in my BalancerFactory.